# How to safely refactor (e.g rename fields) DTO classes returned in JAX-RS web service calls?

Tags: java, jax-rs, java-ee-6

I stumbled upon following problem after refactoring of IssueDTO (used as the type of elements in the returned list below):

- generated JSON response has changed dictionary key (keys are used as
  Strings in our selenium tests so refactoring broke the tests)
- jsf page accesses IssueDTO objects using field names (or names converted
  to javabeans-named methods, I'm not sure) but the access is textual,
  not "typed"

```
    @GET
    @Path("/issues/{" + LOCALE_PARAM + "}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<IssueDTO> getSlides(@PathParam(LOCALE_PARAM) final String locale) {
        final Locale currentLocale = (locale == null) ? 
            Locale.getDefault() : new  Locale(locale);
        return issues.getIssuesInLocale(currentLocale);
    }
```

How can I be sure my refactoring would neither break tests nor break jsf pages?
Is there any annotation I can apply to IssueDTO fields so that to "freeze" their names i.e. de-couple java code names from those used by non-statically-typed-javaee-specific contexts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a plain JavaEE application (i.e. JAX-RS with JAXB annotations used for the JSON generation), you could use `@XmlElement(name = "fixedName")` to decouple the actual property names from their XML *AND* JSON representation.

Comment: This would cover attribute name changes but not addition/removal of attributes. I don't think you can enforce any schema with JSON. You'd have to create an XSD and map your object model to the JAXB classes to ensure 100% compatibility.